# Default radio buttons to unchecked if model property is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When a user loads up the page for the first time and hasn't made a selection, I need the radio buttons to be unchecked. Once they select an option I need it to save their selection. Since it has to be based on data in the model, it seems like jQuery is out.

**Model**

```
public enum AccountType
{
    Checking,
    Savings
}

 public AccountType DDAccountType { get; set; }
```

**Data access**

```
if (oReader["DDAccountType"] != DBNull.Value)
  model.DDAccountType = (oReader["DDAccountType"].ToString() == "Checking") ? AccountType.Checking : AccountType.Savings;
```

**Razor**

```
Checking @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.myModel.DDAccountType, "Checking")
Savings @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.myModel.DDAccountType, "Savings")
```

My guess was since the model value never gets set if it is null, that the radio buttons would be unchecked but it always selects the first one in the tab order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your property to:

```
public AccountType? DDAccountType { get; set; }
```

You need to allow it to be nullable, or a default value will always be passed from the enum, resulting in one of the items always being checked. If you need the property to be required, you can still dictate that some value needs to exist by adding the `[Required]` attribute, which will generate a `ModelState` error if the null value actually gets passed back.